# Change Bundle Seed ID, same Bundle ID for upgrade

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I asked a similar question earlier (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553741/clashing-app-id-that-needs-removing), but perhaps I can ask a different way:

Am I able to update an existing application in the App Store by changing the bundle Seed ID, but keeping the bundle ID the same?

ie, going from:

DFG5TY7E3.com.domain.appName

To:

HGERF562D.com.domain.appName

Does this cause any problems? I know that if I change the bundle ID (com.domain.appName) it will not upgrade, but not sure on the bundle seed id (DFG5TY7E3). See the link above for a full explanation as to why I need to do this...

Answer (score 2):

So I have spoken to Apple today via the phone. They have suggested the following:

I can use a new Bundle Seed ID as long as I am not using the device Keychain in my app (whatever that is?)

The quote this article:

> Note: If you are using the device
>   Keychain in your application, be sure
>   to select the same Bundle Seed ID that
>   you used for your other applications
>   from the Bundle Seed ID pop-up menu.

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1680.html

From that they summised that it is not necessary for me to use the same bundle seed ID. I will test this and let you know before I mark this as answered.

Comment: The Keychain is used to securely store sensitive data, such as username and passwords.

Comment: Link in answer to Apple's doc is dead - *"Sorry, that page cannot be found"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. The seed is actually part of the bundle ID. DFG5TY7E3.com.domain.appName is a totally different bundle than HGERF562D.com.domain.appName.

Comment: Do I have any options at all? I'm stuck with HGERF562D.com.domain.appName which was setup in error as a test, but now I cannot delete it, so cannot create the App ID I really need!

Comment: @mootymoots: If you haven't already submitted that other bundle ID to the store and had it approved, use on of your TI to request that they change the bundle name for you. You may even be able to get them to do this without consuming a TI, but you'll surely have to email the support people for the provisioning portal.

Comment: OK - I did raise a TI for this and they've said it's not them and I'm waiting for devprograms[at]apple to get back to me... I really hope they can resolve this for me, otherwise I am completely stuffed.

Comment: Please see my updated answer on this that came from Apple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557549/change-bundle-seed-id-same-bundle-id-for-upgrade/4596304#4596304

Answer (score 0):

So, can I change the bundle seed id for an App Store app?